# How to give different IAM permission per realtime database on firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, permissions, google-iam

Currently, we have an application in production using firebase. We have a project per environment: `develop` and `production`.

I have seen that we can create multiple databases and we can have multiple hosting sites. Which makes it perfect to create multiple environments in the same project.

The issue is that in `develop` environment we have multiple people(DEVELOPERS) with editor access to the database. In `production`, we want that only one person have access.

If there a way to restrict permissions per database?

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to restrict what Firebase features a collaborator can access within a project, the level of granularity you want is not. There is no way to give a collaborator on a project different level of access to different database instances in that project, or to different hosting sites.

The common way to set up the multiple variants is by creating a separate project for each of your `develop` and `production` apps.